# ContentPanel Collapse direction

Tags: java, gxt

I think it is a easy issue but i cannot find the solution searching with the correct "keywords".

How can i change my ContentPanel collapse/exapnd from up/down to left/right?

Thank you so much for you help!

I tried these code but i doesn't work.

```
    west = new ContentPanel();
    BorderLayoutData westData = new BorderLayoutData(LayoutRegion.WEST, 150);
    westData.setSplit(true);
    westData.setCollapsible(true);
    westData.setMargins(new Margins(0,5,0,0));
    add(west, westData);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ContentPanel will collapse from top to down and there is no way to change it.
But if you use BorderLayoutData you can have north, east, west, south and center panels. East and west panel would have a collapse/expand directions sideways.

Comment: Thank you so much! From my case, why it doesn't work?
I tried to use BorderLayoutData also.

Comment: You can have a look at this code:
https://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:borderlayout